# Need help with sheet music fragment? It repeats throughout the song so need to be sure

Tags: piano, keyboard, arpeggios

How do I play these notes? I’m aware that I have to play an arpeggio for the top notes but do I play F and C after I finish the arpeggio? Or somehow during the arpeggio??

[image: notes I need help with]

Comment: Please add the title and composer. Future searchers would be likely to search on those terms. Also, knowing the source material may help answerers.

Answer (score 1):

The arpeggio should be played first, then the left-hand octave and the right-hand dotted quarter notes are played together. It will be most effective to play the arpeggio like one would a grace note — just ahead of the beat — so that the LH/RH pair occur on the beat. The whole thing should be done with the damper (sustain) pedal held.

Comment: What is the basis of your determination that the arpeggio should be played first?

Comment: @phoog In the absence of knowing the source material, musical convention. The chord appears to be "purely harmonic" while the RH dyad is providing rhythmic impetus. So I take the latter to be more important in terms of staying with the beat, while the arpeggio can be more for color and less for rhythmic drive.

Answer (score 1):

According to Gould's 'Behind Bars', the arpeggiated notes will be played (downwards) just at the end of the previous bar, finishing with the 3 Fs and the C notes coming exactly on the first beat of the bar shown. That will give the player time to actually get the to treble clef F and C in time to do that. It would be a great help to pedal it all, too - either using sustain (damper) or sostenuto pedal as the top C gets played. It won't matter which pedal, as it appears there's an F major chord throughout that bar shown.

Comment: Why downward?  Which part of the book covers this?

Comment: @phoog - follow the direction of the arrowhead. No need to look in any book! That's why I put (downwards) in those brackets.

Comment: Aha, I didn't see any arrowhead.